# How to use MDC in with hystrix in Spring Boot 2?

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, hystrix, mdc, circuit-breaker

We are using hystrix in our spring boot application. We wants to use MDC for appending specific attributes like **Request Id and Request URI and Loggedin User** to every log statement. This mechanism is not working wherever hystrix is implemented.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "callFallback", commandProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "10000")}, ignoreExceptions = Exception.class)
public GenericResponse callUser(User user) {
  //Implementation
   log.info("Creating user called");
}
```

Its working perfectly fine for non hystrix annotated methods. I do understand that MDC is thread specific and hystrix does executes on seperate thread. Please suggest the work around as i can't comment the hystrix.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HystrixCommandExecutionHook` to ensure flow of `ThreadLocal` or `MDC` variables across all hystrix threads.

You can find complete documentation by netflix [here](https://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/com/netflix/hystrix/strategy/executionhook/HystrixCommandExecutionHook.html).

For more help on how to use hook to solve your purpose, you can refer to this [blog](https://medium.com/@saurav24081996/java-hystrix-and-threadlocals-95ea9e194e83)

In the blog, you can use `MDC.get("key")` & `MDC.set("key", value)` instead of `getThreadLocals()` & `setThreadLocals()` to solve your purpose.

Comment: Thanks @FlapPy I can see that it is ThreadLocal. Can i assume that the data in ThreadLocalUtil.java is thead safe ?

Comment: `ThreadLocalUtil.java` is nothing but a wrapper with functions get/set data from/to a `ThreadLocal` variable. And since `ThreadLocal` is local to a single thread, it is definitely ThreadSafe, until you use Mutable objects like ArrayList, etc